# How to set it to default color when Reset button is clicked on?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrapvalidator

When the page is loaded, I am setting the default color to `#444444`. This is working fine.

Similarly when the RESET button was clicked, I need to set it to defalt color `#444444`:

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#color').val("#444444");
    $('#colorPickerForm').bootstrapValidator({
        feedbackIcons: {
            valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
            invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
            validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
        },
        fields: {
            color: {
                validators: {
                    hexColor: {
                        message: 'The color code is not valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

    $('#colorPicker')
        .colorpicker()
        .on('showPicker changeColor', function(e) {
            $('#colorPickerForm').bootstrapValidator('revalidateField', 'color');
        });

        // When reset is clicked 
        $("#resetcolor").click(function(e){
        $('#color').val("#444444");
    });
});
```

Full JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpu25k1g/44/

Comment: hope your reset is working fine only!

Comment: no its not working ..

Answer (score 3):

If you check the documentation for the colorpicker library you'll see this option:

> .colorpicker('setValue', value)
>   Set a new value for the color picker (also updates everything). Triggers 'changeColor' event.

As such, you can use that method to set the color when the rest button is clicked:

```
$("#resetcolor").click(function(e) {
  $('#color').val("#444444");
  $('#colorPicker').colorpicker('setValue', '#444444');
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/vpu25k1g/48/)

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan your solution works, thanks. However I get 
`Uncaught TypeError: $(...).colorpicker is not a function`. Any idea why i get this error? Also, I can't seem to find the jquery documentation for this function.

Comment: You need to include the colorpicker library in the page - its not a standard method.

Answer (score 2):

Just trigger the `change` event after modifying the color.

```
$("#resetcolor").click(function(e) {
    $('#color').val("#444444").trigger('change');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vpu25k1g/50/